# POLIMORFISMO apuntadores

Tags: c++

necesito que el programa utilice polimorfismo en el int main, lo esto acomodando asi pero marca error y dice "no matching function for call to FrecuenciasCardiacas"

```
//Frecuencia Cardiaca
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class FrecuenciasCardiacas
{
 public: //Atributos
    string nombrePersona;
    string apellidoPersona,sexo;
    int mes,dia,anio,da,ma,aa,edad;
    float frecuencia;


//Metodos_
    void datos(string nombre,string apellido,int _mes, int _dia, int _anio,int _da, int _ma, int _aa,int _edad,string _sexo,float _frecuencia)//Constructor
    {
        nombrePersona=nombre;
        apellidoPersona=apellido;
        mes=_mes;
        dia=_dia;
        anio=_anio;
        da=_da;
        ma=_ma;
        aa=_aa;
        edad=_edad;
        sexo=_sexo;
        frecuencia=_frecuencia;//SE PUSO A FRECUENCIA COMO UNA VARIABLE GLOBAL PARA PODER UTILIZARLA EN TODO EL CODIGO
    }

};

class FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento: public FrecuenciasCardiacas
{
public:
    FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento (string nombre,string apellido,int _mes, int _dia, int _anio,int _da, int _ma, int _aa,int _edad,string _sexo,float _frecuencia)
    {
        datos (nombre,apellido,_mes,_dia,_anio,_da,_ma,_aa,_edad,_sexo,_frecuencia);
    }

    void establecerNombrePersona(string nombre)//nombre
    {
        nombrePersona = nombre;
    }

    string obtenerNombrePersona() const
        {
            return nombrePersona;
        }


    void establecerApellido(string apellido)//apellido
        {
            apellidoPersona=apellido;
        }

    string obtenerApellido() const
        {
            return apellidoPersona;
        }

      void establecerDia(int _dia)//DIA
        {
            dia=_dia;
        }
        int obtenerDia() const
        {
            return dia;
        }

        void establecerMes(int _mes)//MES
        {
            mes = _mes;
        }
        int obtenerMes() const
        {
            return mes;
        }

        void establecerAnio(int _anio)//ANIO
        {
            anio = _anio;
        }
        int obtenerAnio()
        {
            return anio;
        }

    int obtenerFecha ()
    {

        if(ma>=mes)
            {
                if(da>=dia)
                {
                    edad=aa-anio;
                }
                else if(da<dia)
                {
                    edad=aa-anio-1;
                }
            }
            else if(dia!=da || mes!=ma)
            {
                edad=aa-anio-1;
            }
            return edad;
    }

    int ObtenerEdad()
    {
        aa=aa-anio;//ANIOS

        return aa;
    }


     void establecerFrecuenciaCardiacaMaxima(float _frecuencia)//FRECUENCIA CARDIACA MAXIMA
     {
        frecuencia = _frecuencia;
     }

     float obtenerFrecuenciaCardiacaMaxima()//FRECUENCIA CARDIACA MAXIMA
     {

        frecuencia=220-edad;
        return frecuencia;
     }


     string obtenerFrecuenciaCardiacaEsperada()//FRECUENCIA CARDIACA ESPERADA
    {
        string parametro;
        if (edad >=0 && edad<1)
        {
            parametro="80 a 160 lpm";
        }
        else if (edad >=1 && edad<=2)
        {
            parametro="80 a 130 lpm";
        }
        else if (edad >=3 && edad<=4)
        {
            parametro="80 a 120 lpm";
        }
        else if (edad >=5 && edad<=9)
        {
            parametro="75 a 115 lpm";
        }
        else if (edad >=10)
        {
            parametro="50 a 100 lpm";
        }
        return parametro;
    }


    void establecerSexoPersona(string _sexo)//SEXOPERSONA
    {
        sexo=_sexo;
    }

    string obtenerSexoPersona() const
    {
        return sexo;
    }

    float obtenerFrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento()//CALCULA LA ZONA DE ENTRENAMIENTOS SEGUN SUS PULSACIONES
    {
        float fce,reposo,intensidad;

        cout<<"\nIntroduzca el valor de su frecuencia cardiaca cuando se encuentra en reposo :  ";
        cin>>reposo;

        cout<<"\nEn una escala de 1-100% escriba la instensidad sobre la cual quiere calcular la zona de entrenamiento:";
        cin>>intensidad;

        fce=((frecuencia-reposo)* intensidad)+reposo;

        if (fce>=50 && fce<60)
        {
            cout <<"Su zona de entrenamiento es ZONA 1 : MUY SUAVE:) "<<endl;
        }

        else if (fce>=60 && fce<70)
        {
            cout <<"Su zona de entrenamiento es ZONA 2 : SUAVE/FACIL "<<endl;
        }

        else if (fce>=70 && fce<80)
        {
            cout <<"Su zona de entrenamiento es ZONA 3 : MODERADA "<<endl;
        }

        else if (fce>=80 && fce<90)
        {
            cout <<"Su zona de entrenamiento es ZONA 4 : INTENSA "<<endl;
        }

        else if (fce>=90 && fce<100)
        {
            cout <<"Su zona de entrenamiento es ZONA 5 : MAXIMA "<<endl;
        }

        return fce;

    }

};

int main()
{
    FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento fre;
    FrecuenciasCardiacas * ap1 = &fre;
    ap1 -> datos ();

    cout << fre.obtenerNombrePersona() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Un *par* de apuntes: ¿ Es necesario todo ese código ? ¿ No se puede condensar en menos de 225 líneas ? Y, ya puestos, ¿ Seguro que es ese el error que te da ? ¿ No has omitido nada del mensaje ? Quizás deberías pasarte por [mcve], y quizás también por [un exceso de código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879/19610). Un saludo.

Comment: De acuerdo en que parece demasiado código. Además, no indicas la línea donde se produce ese error.

Comment: revertí los cambios que hiciste, no es correcto que cambies sin razón tu pregunta por ese contenido de puntos suspensivos @user103440

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, como te han comentado, tienes que presentar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema.

Elaborar un ejemplo mínimo es importante porque te puede ayudar a encontrar el origen del problema por tus propios medios.

En tu caso el ejemplo mínimo para el primer error podría quedar así:

```
class FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento
{
public:
  FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento (string nombre,string apellido,int _mes, int _dia, int _anio,int _da, int _ma, int _aa,int _edad,string _sexo,float _frecuencia)
  { }
};

int main()
{
  FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento fre;
}
```

Cuatro líneas de código que reproducen el mensaje de error. No hay polimorfismo ni punteros...

El problema aquí es que la clase `FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento` **no tiene** un constructor por defecto. En C++ **todas** las clases tienen un constructor por defecto... hasta que se declaran constructores específicos, en ese caso hay que declarar el constructor por defecto de forma explícita si se quiere seguir usando:

```
class FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento
{
public:
  // c++11
  FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento() = default;

  // c++98
  FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento()
  { }

  FrecuenciasCardiacasEntrenamiento (string nombre,string apellido,int _mes, int _dia, int _anio,int _da, int _ma, int _aa,int _edad,string _sexo,float _frecuencia)
  { }
};
```

El segundo error es prácticamente idéntico:

```
Startprog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:219:19: error: no matching function for call to 'FrecuenciasCardiacas::datos()'
 219 | ap1 -> datos ();
     | ^
```

El problema es que no tienes una función `datos` que no admita parámetros:

```
class FrecuenciasCardiacas
{
public:
  void datos(string nombre,string apellido,int _mes, int _dia, int _anio,int _da, int _ma, int _aa,int _edad,string _sexo,float _frecuencia)
  { }
};
```

Tienes que crear una versión de `datos` que no acepte argumentos... o pedirle todos esos datos al usuario y llamar a la función `datos` que ya tienes... la decisión es tuya.

Como ves los errores no tienen nada que ver con el polimorfismo sino que son llamadas a funciones que no existen.